# OCL - iterate for each item

Tags: ocl

I have a class A with a collection of other classes (B).

How do I represent in OCL that for each class (B) in the collection there's a constraint on a field ?

I thought something like:

```
A.collection->iterate().field = SomeConstraint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your terminology is a bit confusing. Do you mean you have something like

> A--------->* B
>
> ```
>    bs
> ```

What do you expect `SomeConstraint` to be?

I guess you're looking for so-called *invariants* in OCL for class A:

```
  context A
  inv allOK : bs->forall(b | ...)
```

**Update:**
If you want to count, the easiest way is not `iterate`, but doing `select(...)->count()`. Maybe that simplifies your matter.

Comment: forall() is just a boolean constraint... i want to count something, i just don't understand the iterate syntax.

Comment: we cannot help if you don´t precise what you want. Iterate in OCL is just a generic iterator expression so we cannot just explain how to use it in a few rods because it´s too generic. See the OCL documentation for that or tell us more exactly what you need so that we can help on your example